# Hide action buttons on Lock Screen Mode - iOS Notification Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift4, swift4.2

I want to hide these action buttons during Lock Screen Mode.

[image]

Is there a way to detect that in iOS ?

```
if action == "allow.action" {

    APIService.shared.updateCpeDeviceACL(cpe: cpe,vlan: vlan, device: deviceMac ?? "", portalUrl: "", acl: true, caller: self)

    if(alertId != nil){
        APIService.shared.deleteAlert(id: alertId ?? "", caller: self)
    } else {
        print("alertId = nil detetected !")
    }

    if(notificationType != "new-device"){

        if(quarantineId != nil){
            APIService.shared.allowDeviceToNetwork(id: quarantineId ?? "", caller: self)
        } else {
            print("quarantineId = nil detetected !")
        }

    }


} else if action == "delete.action" {

    APIService.shared.deleteAlert(id: alertId ?? "", caller: self)

} else if action == "block.action" {

    APIService.shared.updateCpeDeviceACL(cpe: cpe,vlan: vlan, device: deviceMac ?? "", portalUrl: "", acl: false, caller: self)

    if(alertId != nil){
        APIService.shared.deleteAlert(id: alertId ?? "", caller: self)
    } else {
        print("alertId = nil detetected !")
    }


    if(notificationType != "new-device"){

        if(quarantineId != nil){
            APIService.shared.denyDeviceToNetwork(id: quarantineId ?? "", caller: self)
        } else {
            print("quarantineId = nil detetected !")
        }

    }


} else {
    awakeFromNotification = true
}
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to actionable notifications? If so somewhere in your code you should be able to see:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([someCategory])
```

When the someCategory (whatever name used in your app) was created it should receive those actions as a parameter. You can modify them there.